# What does the phrase "sliding in and out of drifts" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me understand the meaning of the phrase "sliding in and out of drifts" in the following sentence from the description of the game "KartRider Rush+" (not available online):

*You should give those thumps a warm-up before each race in the game, they’ll need to be in shape for all that **sliding in and out of drifts**.*

I know drifting [is a driving technique where the driver intentionally oversteers, with loss of traction, while maintaining control and driving the car through the entirety of a corner.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drifting_(motorsport)) I am confused by the words "sliding in and out" here.

Here is a description of the game from a different source:

*The kart racing sensation enjoyed by over 300M players worldwide is back and better than ever with more style, more game modes, more thrill! Race with friends or just play it solo through a variety of gameplay* modes.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It is talking about how you will have to keep pushing the joystick on your gaming console left and right during the drifts.

"Slide" simply means *to cause something to move easily and without interruption over a surface.* It is referring to how the car slides during the drift.

"Sliding in and out of drifts" is racing terminology. In the image (source: google), the car slides into the drift (starting from 1 to maybe halfway after 2), and then it slides out of the drift (starting from 3 to 5).

[image]

This is "sliding."
 [image]

I previously thought "sliding" was referring to how you have to control (or slide) the joystick while entering the turn in the track and how you have to pull it back when you are getting out of that turn. But it's actually talking about the car sliding in and out of the drifts.